# Should we split up the [shadowbox] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I was just looking at [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542208/zoom-image-and-block-site-with-a-transparent-black-background) on Stack Overflow and thought it could really use a generic shadow-box tag, but it seems the tag [shadowbox](/questions/tagged/shadowbox) is being used for a particular plugin of that name ([shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/)).  However, a [*shadowbox*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_box) is also a well known web structure for viewing content originating from before their use in web pages.  [This blog post](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/30-efficient-jquery-lightbox-plugins/) Shows how prevalent the structure is (under a synonym, light box)

My question is: Should that tag be split into maybe [shadowbox-js](/questions/tagged/shadowbox-js) and [shadowbox](/questions/tagged/shadowbox)? Or should it be left as is?

<sub>Disclaimer: This is my first question of this type and I really have no idea what I'm doing.  Please feel free to correct me where necessary.</sub>

Comment: Absolutely no complaints, you made your point clear. One thing though: *> a shadowbox is also a well known web structure for viewing content* — `[citation needed]`. I've never heard that term before, maybe someone can give me a few hints?

Comment: @slhck thank you very much. :)  I've updated my post with some references.

Comment: I think the term "lightbox" is better known, so maybe it should be `shadowbox-js` (a specific implementation) and `lightbox` (the generic term), with possibly `shadowbox` as a synonym for `lightbox`?

Comment: @hammar that sounds good to me... who is qualified to do that though?